# tPanels shown on top of Panel that contains tchart is transparent (Delphi)

Tags: delphi, teechart

I have a frame with a panel.
on the panel is a tchart graph and custom panel that overlays the graph (so it's on top of the graph, with the user toggling which one is showing).
Additionally, I have 3 other panels that contain text, that user also toggles visible/not visible.

the problem: starting in Delph 10.4, the panel is showing sections of the chart.  the problem didn't exist in Delphi Seattle (and untested in 10.2 and 10.3), but in 10.4, I can't show the 3 panels without showing sections of the chart.
To replicate, add a panel to a form, put a chart on the panel.  add a second panel to the form, not visible, with some text.  add a right click menu to set the panel visible.  sections of the chart are 'bleeding through' the panel.  This also happens with group boxes.
this is what it looks like:
[image]

question is: how can I get the panels to show correctly?

How I want it to look:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I can reproduce this in Delphi 10.3 Rio

This happens only if the panel is added as child control of the TChart component and has its [ParentBackground](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.ParentBackground) property enabled (enabled by default).

I'm guessing that `TChart` background is drawn with transparency at some level. And when `ParentBackground` property of any child component is enabled backgroud of such components is also drawn using transparency.

Disabling the `ParentBackground` property of your Panels will solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you.  Sometimes, it's the simplest things...